# Can i Use System.Web.UI.Page.ClientScript in ASp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, clientscript

I am Trying to Register STart up Script in my ASP.Net MVC 3.0

I know I can use this syntax in VB.Net
But not sure if i can use it in MVC

```
System.Web.UI.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "co", "coInit(0, 'R');", true);
```

Intellisense is not picking up the properties for Page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have the Page object as a Web-Forms, but you can use ViewBag property on controller and write an script later write to your Views.

In your Controller

```
ViewBag.coInit = "<script type="text/javascript">coInit(0, 'R');</script>"
```

In your View (if you use MVC3, use Raw helper for wirte javascript without encoding.)

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.coInit)
```